# Question regarding kinetic energy and final velocity of the body

Tags: work

Suppose there is block of mass 'M' kg . You applied the force of 'F'N on it , as a result it get accelerated. Then it acquired final velocity 'v'.

The kinetic energy of the block is 1/2(MV²).

My question is: will the block acquire the kinetic energy of magnitude 1/2(MV²)
When you apply force ?

Or it will possess that energy after reaching the point where its velocity become 'v'.

I am very confused about it , when I came across this question:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-qa/question/in-a-hydroelectric-power-station-water-is-allowed-to-fall-at-the-rate-of-2000/&ved=2ahUKEwiXqYr7gun3AhUBTmwGHZS8Cx4QFnoECBsQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2HOhz_UcaqxBlmaaVTLADA

Answer (score 0):

It will possess that kinetic energy when reaching the `V` velocity, as you can guess from the fact that the formula uses this `V` value.

E = 1/2(MV²) means: When a body of mass M moves with a velocity V, it has a kinetic energy of E (as computed by the formula), at that point in time.

If at some point earlier or later in time, it moves with a different velocity, than it has a different kinetic energy at that point in time.

If you apply a force to a body, thus accelerating it, then the kinetic energy increases over time, as velocity increases over time.

Answer (score 0):

The kinetic energy of a body is a function of it's velocity. Velocity can in turn be expressed as a function of time. In other words, the kinetic energy  of a body is a function of time. To answer your question, the block acquires that kinetic energy at that instant only. Since the work done is equal to force times displacement, think of it this way:
The longer you apply the force, the further the block moves and a larger amount of work is being converted to kinetic energy which manifests in the block's velocity at that instant of time.

Comment: So , can I make conclusion that , the block will possess that energy when it reach the point where its final velocity become 'v'

Comment: Yeah, that is correct.

Comment: Can you pls explain me the question that I have attached ? . Does it tell to find kinetic energy of water at 25 m height or 75 m height?. I don't understand when it says that find the kinetic energy when it falls through 25 m height. What does it mean by 'falls through' ?

Comment: They are asking you to find the kinetic energy of the water after it has fallen through a height of 25 metres. Since the zero level for gravitational potential energy is chosen to be the ground, you have to find the kinetic energy of the water when it's 75 metres above ground.

Comment: So ,  the water will have 5 x 10⁵ J energy only at that point where it is 75 m  above the ground?

Comment: Yeah you have the right answer